# How can I distinguish columns with the same names from a join query in the results?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I'm running a query that has a lot of joining between tables. The problem is that the tables have columns that have a name that are also available in the other tables. This is only a problem in the results since the `title` and `id` columns, for example, appears multiple times. Can I format it so the results can have columns like "table1.id" and "table2.id"? I know I can do that manually, but to do that for all the columns is a hassle.

Edit: This is not a duplicate of the other users who are told to do "table1.id as id1, table2.id as id2, etc." This question is different in that I'm asking how to do it automatically. In the screenshot I provided, I have 7 tables being joined... each with multiple columns. Many of those tables have the same column names so **I need to avoid doing it manually.**

[image]

Comment: Hint:  `tag.id as tag_id, l.id as l_id, . . .`

Comment: @GordonLinoff Like I said: I know I can do that manually, but to do that for all the columns is a hassle. I have perhaps 5 tables, each with many columns.

Comment: @Shadow, like I said... I already know how to do it manually. I'm asking how to do it automatically. This is not a duplicate.

Comment: There is no way of doing this automatically within sql. Added a 2nd duplicate to make this even more explicit.